# .NET Framework 4.8 project that references to a dll with another .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, frameworks, .net-4.8

I have a project, Project X, which is built using .NET Framework 4.8. Within this project, I've included a reference to Y.dll, which is designed for .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Unfortunately, Y.dll is not compatible with .NET Framework 4.8. Consequently, I'm seeking a way to ensure that the reference to Y.dll exclusively utilizes .NET Framework 4.7.2.
Is this possible?

I attempted to modify the configuration file of the project without result.

Comment: Assemblies targeting 4.7.2 are normally compatible with 4.8 so without further information this is difficult to diagnose: You should normally be able to target your y.dll to 4.8. What is the incompatibility you talk about?

Comment: On Y.dll i have an override of DataGridViewControl.
On BeginEdit it returns "object reference not set to an instance of an object" without any clue of what it could be. 

DataGridViewCell cell = dgvFilter.Rows[iIndex].Cells["hello"]
dgvFilter.CurrentCell = cell;
dgvFilter.BeginEdit(true);

Obviously dgvFilter.CurrentCell is properly initialized.

I attempted to search for 4.8 changes on DataGridView but can't find any of useful.
If i create a new simple project with an override of DataGridViewControl, it works. So it's something on by Y.dll project. Can't figure out what.

Comment: Build a Debug version of Y. Then reference this Debug version DLL. Now, you can set breakpoints and debug. When finished, don't forget to reference the Release version again.